# SQL to convert timestamp into YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZZ

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to convert current timestamp which is YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MM.SS to YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZZ in DB2 and using below syntax

```
VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT TIMESTAMP,"YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZZ") as DATE_FORMAT
```

Also tried below

```
VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT TIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD''T''HH:mm:ssZZ') as DATE_FORMAT
```

Error

```
Fomrat String "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZZ" is not valid for VARCHAR_FORMAT function
```

Any suggestion on how include T in the timestamp ?

Comment: Is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZZ"` working?

Comment: no ,getting same error as above

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?  Db2 for IBM i for instance doesn't support time zones in a timestamp.

Comment: I am using Dbeaver to connect DB2 on prem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Db2 for LUW doesn't have a TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE data type, so you have to specify the timezone part of a timestamp externally.
For example, if you want to express the current timestamp in the current timezone of the Db2 instance owner, you may do this as follows.

```
values 
   translate (to_char (current timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'T', ' ')
|| translate (substr (to_char (current timezone, 'S00,0000'), 1, 6), ':', ',')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.                                                                                                       This helps - I modified as below as I was looking for the format 
`2022-08-11T14:55:31.303-0500 ` 
`translate (to_char (current timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.ms'), 'T', ' ')
|| '-0' ||translate (substr (to_char (current timezone, 'S000,00'), 2, 4), '', ',') `

Comment: Dangerous modification. current timezone may be positive and offset may be more than 9 hours. Use `substr (to_char (current timezone, 'S000000'), 1, 5)` instead to get `{sign}HHMM` format.